# Typescript how to change the function result without modifying the function

Tags: typescript

how to let multiply & subtract executed once addOne function executed and affect its result
**((2+1)*2)-1 =5**

```
class MathClass{

   @subtract(1)
   @multiply(2)
   addOne(number:number) {
       return number+1;
   }
}

console.log(new MathClass().addOne(2)) //should print 5
```

Comment: This looks like a good way to write extremely confusing and hard to debug code. Is there a specific problem you're trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: ok sorry, for this 
I am trying to let the result of calling addOne function in last line to be 5 instead of 3
by using subtract and multiply function in mentioned order but without modifying the addOne function code 
it is a quiz :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create 2 decorator for 2 operator as you want. With you case, you can create a decorator factory to reuse the code:

```
function operatorFactory(operator: (result: number) => number) {
  return (
    target: Object,
    propertyName: string,
    propertyDescriptor: PropertyDescriptor,
  ) => {
    const method = propertyDescriptor.value;

    propertyDescriptor.value = function (...args: any[]) {

      const result = method.apply(this, args); // Call original function

      return operator(result); // Call operator
    }

    return propertyDescriptor;
  } 
}

function subtract(subtrahend: number = 1) {
  return operatorFactory((num: number) => {
    return num - subtrahend;
  });
};

function multiply(factors: number = 1) {
  return operatorFactory((num: number) => {
    return num * factors;
  });
};
```

As you see `operatorFactory` get a parameter is a function, the function define the way you do with the `result` - the result of before operator.

`subtract` decorator get a parameter is a number - subtrahend, and it calls `operatorFactory` with "subtract" operator.

The same for `multiply`.

Note, the order of method decorator is very important. With your case `((number+1)*2)-1` , the order will be as you think:

```
class MathClass {
  @subtract(1)
  @multiply(2)
  addOne(number: number) {
    return number + 1;
  }
}

console.log(new MathClass().addOne(2)) // Print 5
```

If you reverse the order, you will have a operator like `((number+1)-1)*2`, with code as:

```
class MathClass {
  @multiply(2)
  @subtract(1)
  addOne(number: number) {
    return number + 1;
  }
}

console.log(new MathClass().addOne(2)) // Print 4
```

Comment: Thank you a lot dear its saved my time and I will try to fully understand the idea of this